# Adding an internet printer with socket to Mac

Tags: macos, network, printing

Scenario - I have three printers that I need to print to remotely.  All three have a dedicated port number (eg 1.1.1.1:443) and I can connect to each in a browser.

How do I add them to MacOS?  It strips the port and just adds the IP address.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: 443 is for https. Are you sure that just isn't the port number for the web connection?  IPP uses 631; and 9100 is used for HPJetDirect. Can you not configure the printers?

Comment: I'm having an issue opening up ports on the Vodafone router so might have to buy them one, I just gave 443 as an example as that one is open and working.

I'm looking for maybe a URL that forces Mac settings to keep the port number

Comment: Oh hang on: when you say "remotely" -- you mean not on the same network, but somewhere else entirely? That's a bit more complicated. That's usually done with specialist tunnelling software, like a VPN. Otherwise, yes, you'll need to open the port 631 on the router for IPP.

Comment: Yea, I need the solution at the Mac end not the router end.  

How do I get the Mac to _not_ strip the port number from the IP address?

Comment: As said, I don't think it strips the port number, but assigns either 631 or 9100, based on the protocol used. Is your router allowing those ports through?

Comment: If you use https as the protocol, then the port number will be 443.